# Elements for array getting from server, randomly different order (swift)

Tags: ios, arrays, swift

In viewDidLoad I have such code:

```
Alamofire.request(.GET, "http://my1test.ru/applejesus.php?task=getCategoryCount").responseString(encoding: NSUTF8StringEncoding) { (request, response, string, error) -> Void in
        let count = string!.toInt()!
        println(count)

        for var i=1; i<=count; i++ {
          //  println(i)
            lib.httpGetAsNSData("http://my1test.ru/applejesus.php?task=getCategory&categoryNumber=\(i)") {result in
                let json = JSON(data: result)
                let title = json["title"].stringValue
                println("title: "+title)
                if title.isEmpty == false {
                NSURLSession.sharedSession().dataTaskWithURL(NSURL(string: "http://my1test.ru/aj/"+lib.urlencode(title)+".png")!) { (data, response, error) in
                    self.images.append(data)
                     self.catTitles.append(title)
                    //self.tableViewObject.reloadData()
                    }.resume()
                }
            }
            }
        }
    }
```

First we request for categories count, second we loading their titles and adding them into array. Also there is an NSData-array with images for each category. Images loading from server too.

Now please look at println("title: "+title)

So my question is that order of parsed titles can be changed randomly. Why it happens, how should I fix it and if it not an random, what have I done wrong?

In screenshots below you can see that 1 element always in different position

If it needed, httpGetAsNSData listing:

```
 class func httpGetAsNSData(url: String, completion: NSData -> Void) {
    if url.isEmpty == false { var request = NSMutableURLRequest(URL: NSURL(string: url)!)

    request.HTTPMethod = "GET"

    request.addValue("text/html", forHTTPHeaderField: "Content-Type")
    request.addValue("Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/44.0.2403.125 Safari/537.36", forHTTPHeaderField: "User-Agent")
    request.addValue("text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/webp,*/*;q=0.8", forHTTPHeaderField: "Accept")
    request.addValue("gzip, deflate, sdch", forHTTPHeaderField: "Accept-Encoding")
    request.addValue("max-age=0", forHTTPHeaderField: "Cache-Control")

    var session = NSURLSession.sharedSession()

    let task = session.dataTaskWithRequest(request, completionHandler: { data, response, error in

        if error != nil {

            println(error.localizedDescription)

        }

        completion(data)

    })

    task.resume()
    }
}
```

[image]

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is because you do a Asynchronous request (`dataTaskWithURL`) for each item, so the order the strings get added to the array (`self.catTitles.append(title)`) is different every time.

You can have a fixed order by sorting your `Array` for example alphabetically:

```
var sortedNames = names.sorted { $0.localizedCaseInsensitiveCompare($1) == NSComparisonResult.OrderedAscending }
```

For more information about sorting see [this link](https://thatthinginswift.com/sort-and-sorted/)

---

---

To keep the array positions first update your `for-loop`

```
for var i=0; i<count; i++ {
```

Then add empty values for each item in your `Array`

```
self.catTitles.append("")
```

Put the request in a separate method

```
func doBackendCall(integer: Int) {
    lib.httpGetAsNSData("http://my1test.ru/applejesus.php?task=getCategory&categoryNumber=\(integer)") {result in
        ...
    }
}
```

Then add the text for the cat title at the correct index

```
self.catTitles[integer] = title
```

Remember you have to do the same for the images.

Here's the full code

```
for var i=0; i<count; i++ {
    self.doBackendCall(i)
}

func doBackendCall(integer: Int) {
    lib.httpGetAsNSData("http://my1test.ru/applejesus.php?task=getCategory&categoryNumber=\(integer)") {result in
        let json = JSON(data: result)
        let title = json["title"].stringValue
        println("title: "+title)
        if title.isEmpty == false {
            NSURLSession.sharedSession().dataTaskWithURL(NSURL(string: "http://my1test.ru/aj/"+lib.urlencode(title)+".png")!) { (data, response, error) in
                self.images.append(data)
                self.catTitles[integer] = title
                //self.tableViewObject.reloadData()
                }.resume()
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: But what should I do because I need such order as on the server? Ease category has it's own number, image and title. It's very hard me to understand how variable "i" can has random value in construction like "for var i=0; i<some.count; i++"

Comment: The problem isn't the variable 'i'. It is that the dataTaskWithURL is asynchronous, so you don't know which request finishes first. I have updated my answer so you put the titles in the correct position.

Comment: Ok, I'll check it in the evening, apperciate your help very much!

Comment: No problem, happy to help. Please upvote and accept my answer if it helped you.